# Accessing object from an object

Tags: angularjs, json

Am trying to access the value of usertype inside result but am not able to do this. I tried something like below, where data am getting is the Below JSON

```
if(data.result.usertype === 2){
  console.log("redirect to type 2 user")
}
else if(data.result.usertype === 3){ 
  console.log("redirect to type 3 user")
}
```

And the JSON is as below

```
{
  "success": true,
  "token": "abc",
  "result": {
    "_id": "57bd7c857e8d30893a9fc45b",
    "usertype": "2",
    "created_date": "1472035973314"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `==` , Normaly `===` is strict type equality operator. It not only checks whether two are equal in value but also of the same type. In your case it is a string,

So use `==` which just checks only for equality

```
if(data.result.usertype == 2){
  console.log("redirect to type 2 user")
}
```

**EDIT:**

Since you already know the result.usertype is a String, you can stick with the same way and use it as below,

```
if(data.result.usertype === "2"){
  console.log("redirect to type 2 user")
}
```

Comment: If @nsr knows for sure the JSON will stay like this, I'd go with `data.result.usertype === "2"`. It's always better to use strict equality when you know the type of your variable.

Comment: @ValLeNain Yes valid, modified the answer